# Cucumber: Multiple tags not running the scenarios

Tags: ruby, automation, cucumber, appium

Multiple tags in the cucumber doesnt run the scenarios.

I have two different tags, tagged to two different scenarios under the same feature file. I try to run both the scenarios that are tagged, using the cucumber tags command

`cucumber --tags @billing --tags @important`

When I run this, cucumber doesn't recognize the scenarios, it provides the output like

```
0 scenarios
0 steps
0m0.000s
```

But when I run the tags individually, like `cucumber --t @billing` the cucumber is able to recognize and runs the scenario. Any idea why?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your feature file also? Your tag filter will run scenarios which are tagged with both billing and important tags. Are both the scenarios having both the tags?

Comment: @Grasshopper No! One scenario contains `@billing` tag and the other `@important` tag. I didnt realise this command has to have both the tags in the same scenario. 

Could you please let me know the command, for my case? What I if I have different tags in two scenarios each? 

for eg: scenario 1 tagged with `@important`
           scenario 2 tagged with `@billing`

I want to run both  `scenario1` and `scenario2`

Comment: Use --tags @billing,@important

Comment: Great! Works! Thanks :) In case if 

Scenario 1 contains : @billing @important
and
Scenario 2 contains: @checkout @notimportant

Will the above command work ? 

`cucumber --tags @billing,@checkout,@notimportant,@important?`

Comment: Yes it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Simply if you define like above ( `cucumber --tags @billing --tags @important` ) , there should be a scenario having both `@billing` and `@important` tags.

if you are looking for cucumber to pick up when matching any of the tags,
use as below.

`cucumber --tags @billing , @important`